# How can I be sure that gaming graphics work?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

I saw in the windows experience index that there are graphics and gaming graphics. How can I make sure that when I play a game instead of graphics, gaming graphics work (gaming graphics in my laptop are much higher than normal graphics)

Answer (score 1):

There are no separate **graphics** and **gaming graphics** cards / drivers of your computers. It's just the assessment of your pc for two different purposes (general use / browsing / video... OR gaming)

When you play games, of course your gaming graphics's performance will determine its quality.

Answer (score 0):

As Máté Juhász stated, there is only 1 GPU controller on your machine. Whether it's a discrete GPU or an integrated solution into your CPU, the hardware rendering your graphics[a.k.a the display adapter your monitors are plugged into] output controls both 'graphics' & 'gaming graphics'.

You can't choose which one to use as it's all encompassing.

I'm not a huge fan of the Windows Experience Index, as the verbiage MS uses to describe performance can sometimes be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Gaming graphics is just a term used by Windows in order to help users have a hint on their laptop gaming capabilities. The better the score the more possibilities to run more complex, graphically speaking, games. As well as higher resolution and/or FPS.

As stated from people before, there is only one GPU controller on your laptop and shouldn't you worry.